# Javascript to set part of website

Tags: javascript, html, string, variables, web

Is there any way I could, using only Javascript and HTML, have a page with only a line of text and a text box, and when someone hits enter in the text box, it would set the text on the page, not just for them, but for anyone seeing the page?

EDIT: If there was a way to self-modify the HTML page to show whatever was typed, while unstable, that would be best in this case - don't ask.

EDIT2: If not, how could I do this in PHP? Here's kind of my idea: A very sketchy idea of a twitter-like site, kind of a "1.4 seconds of fame" thing. Anyone can post anything, and until someone posts on top of it, the entire world can see it. I guess it's like a public chatroom with only the 3 latest messages visible. Here's a basic, non-functional HTML prototype: 
http://uploadir.com/u/i774cx

Comment: Like a chat system?  I would google "javascript chat".

Comment: Not really. You would need a server-side language (e.g. PHP) to actually store and retrieve the text the visitors enter.

Comment: It already exists btw http://www.dark-chat.info/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes … but only if the JavaScript is running on the server (e.g. via [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)).

You can't record changes to data stored on the server entirely with client side scripting. The closest you could come would be make an [HTTP PUT](http://www.w3.org/QA/2008/10/understanding-http-put.html) request, but even that would require a web server which supported PUT and gave the client permission to add the file.